# CakePHP filtering fields according to time availability

Tags: cakephp, datetime, time, cakephp-2.3

I'm using Cake 2.3.1.
I'm developing an app which manages the transports of customers. Since our human and material resources are limited I need to implement the "availability flag" for every operator and vehicle. i.e. if 'operator1' and 'vehicle3' are scheduled to a service (31/02/2013 from 8:30 to 12:30) they should not be available to be assigned in other services in that period of time.

I'm completely lost in 'period-of-time' management. I thought to make a new table ('availabilities') to manage every 'available flag' but the thing resulted too complex compared to my actual skills (more questions blocking me after a little step).

I just started using PHP and CakePHP so if it is possible I need you to point me in the right direction. 

Is there a way to filter operators and vehicles based on their availability in my `service/add` view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way, but - it will get a bit complicated.  You'll just need to store the times that they're scheduled, and then check against a time you're trying to schedule for (likely Ajax, but depends on the layout of your CMS).

Once you start going down that path, come back with more specific question(s), but just know 1) yes, it's certainly doable, but 2) there isn't some magic "findButFilterOutNotAvailable()" method (unfortunately) :)

Comment: woah... thanks, that will be a challenge!
Shall I edit this question or make new ones?

Comment: new question for each individual code problem/question you have